# The Commutative Property in C and other Programming Languages

Tags: c, string

The Commutative Property in C and other Programming Languages

In C, to reference a character in a string, most programmers would usually do str[i].
So if they need the 7th character when str="Hello World", they would do str[6] and get
'W';

Now the C language implements the commutative property for addtion.  So the statement
'i = 4 + 9' evaluates exactly the same as 'i = 9 + 4'.    For strings, many times you
will see the above example expressed as 'str + 6', as if there were an addition, and
in a sense there is (add 6 to the starting offset, which is represented by 'str').

Now expanding on this last example, because of the commutative property, you might then
assume you could also write that as '6 + str' and it should evaulate to the same.  And
indeed it does that, without any problem or compiler warnings.

Now here's the amazing surprise.
Even further expansion of this last example '6 + str', would lead one to believe that,
if the commutative property is indeed at work here too, a rewrite of that example
should also work, namely the eexpression: '6[str]'.
And guess what: IT WORKS!
I checked glibc/gcc (no special flags).

Now here's my question.
Is anybody aware of a language that uses string indices, which language ostensibly
implements the commutative property, but where the expression rewritten in the latter
form (mutatis mutandis) does NOT compile or where it issues a compile or run time
warning or error?

Comment: Probably most languages that allow string indexing.

Comment: The Commutative Property is a property of addition.  Your example works because it involves pointer arithmetic (addition, specifically), and *addition is already commutative.*  But even if this worked in other languages, it would have no utility, since you would never write it in the reverse form under ordinary use.

Answer (score 3):

1. In C there is no string type in both the language and the standard library
2. Programmers abstract a string as an array of `char`

   - as a consequence your "string" is an array `char[]`
   - in C arrays obey to the [pointer arithmetic](https://www.google.com/#q=pointer%20arithmetic)
3. in other languages such as C++ you can achieve a result similar to your goal by **not** providing the `[]` operator for your `string` type.

Answer (score 1):

C is very unusual in this regard.

e.g. Python:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Jan  2 2013, 13:56:14) 
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 4 + 9 == 9 + 4
True
>>> a = ["apple", "banana", "cherry"]
>>> a[2]
'cherry'
>>> 2[a]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Perl:

```
$ cat /tmp/ary.pl
#! /usr/bin/perl -w

@a = qw(apple banana cherry);

print $a[2], "\n";
print 2[$a], "\n";

$ perl /tmp/ary.pl
syntax error at /tmp/ary.pl line 6, near "2["
Execution of /tmp/ary.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

etc. What you have found is less a consequence of the commutative property of addition than a side effect of C's approach to pointer syntax, which allows a program to add an integer to a pointer to obtain a new pointer. Most other languages do not implement array indexing this way, and impose stricter requirements on the syntax (such as requiring the `s` in an expression like `s[a]` to be an enumerable object like an array or list).